# Can I use Inspiring Leader feat while alone?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

My warlock character is in love with herself. Really, she would make Deadpool think she is too narcisistic.

She took the Inspiring Leader feat, but for some reason her party mates did not share her own taste in herself, and departed. Too bad for them, more for me.

Can she give herself a speech on her own greatness (while she is alone in front of her "mirror of truth") to grant herself temporary HP?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## YES!

Inspiring Leader allows you to (emphasis mine):

> Choose up to six friendly creatures **(which can include yourself)** within 30 feet of you who can see or hear you and who can understand you.
>
> <sup>PHB 167</sup>

Is 1 a number included in up to 6? Check
Can you include yourself? Check
Do you need more than one? Not stated anywhere, so no.

The benefits of talking to yourself never looked so good. Even if it is just temporary.

Comment: Like pumping yourself up for a job interview or getting ready to solo a dragon. Same thing, really.

Comment: "The benefits of talking to yourself never looked so good." unless you are an extremely narcissistic warlock, in which case talking to yourself always looked good.